# Is it possible to get total row count in ag-grid api for SSRM model?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid react with server side pagination. When I initially load the grid with rows I have the total count of rows(received from backend) with which ag-grid calculates the pagination data. My page size is 100 and I have about 1000 rows (~ 11 pages)

When I add a row in the grid, I am setting the datasource again using gridApi. In below snippet newRows is page 1 : 100 rows plus the newRow

```
 const updatedDataSource = (newRows) => {
  return {
    getRows: (params) => {
      params.successCallback(newRows);
    },
  };
};
    const ds = updatedDataSource(newRows)
    gridApi.setServerSideDatasource(ds)
```

Is it possible to get the total row count from the params in getRows or from gridApi so that I can set the total in params.successCallback(..) ? When checking the API reference , I can see the pagination related apis are available , total number of pages , last page , first page , getDisplayedRowCount() etc but not the total row count.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some details which I missed in my question:
I am using Partial RowStore.
After reading the documentation, for Partial row store operations like Add/Delete needs to be performed outside the grid and the grid needs to be refreshed.

[Ag grid rowstore](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/26.0.0/react-data-grid/server-side-model-row-stores/)